# Send an email : - Error

Tags: email, record-type, url, record

I  created a send an email button for a custom object called `'Application__c'`, but I was experiencing some issues with filling the related to field, if I exclude it it work fine, but when I'm trying to link it to the current application it gives me the following error:

> Unable to Access Page
>   The value of the "p3_lkid" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

The code I'm using is :

```
 location.replace('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?rtype=a1y&p3_lkid={!Application__c.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Application__c.Id}&p4={!Application__c.Project_Owner_Email__c}&p5=&p24={!Application__c.Consultant_Email__c}&template_id=<mytemplateid>');
```

I think the issue is linked to the rtype, but I cannot seem to find a solution to it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How long is the id provided? It might be expecting a 15 char id, but receiving an 18 char one.

Comment: the id provided is 15 char long , but if I eliminate it it gives me the same error but linked to the rtype field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appeared to be caused by the `'Track Activities'` field not being enabled.